# Регулярное выражением и CLI

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть скрипт, которому при выполнении передается параметр (строка на русском).
Команда запуска: php -f test.php Пример

Этот параметр есть признак, по которому осуществляется поиск по страничке с помощью регулярного выражения.

```
preg_match_all("/ ".$argv[1]."/iU", curl("http://tratata.ru/index.html"), $matches);
```

функция curl возвращает страничку. Так вот... когда я этот скрипт запускаю в браузере, то все работает отлично, а вот - через командную строку, то результат этого регулярного выражения 0-вой, т.е. регулярное выражение нечего не возвращает. (( Такое впечатление, что тут проблема с кодировкой?

Answer (score 1):

Так сделайте дамп `$argv` и результат `curl()` и сравните кодировки. Если они отличаются, то приводите их к utf-8, при помощи [`mb_convert_encoding()`](http://php.net/mb-convert-encoding) или [`iconv()`](http://php.net/iconv). Если адрес сайта может быть любым, тогда необходимо сначала определять кодировку по заголовку `Content-Type`.

И еще, значения из внешних источников, подставляемые в регулярку, нужно обязательно экранировать при помощи [preg_quote()](http://php.net/preg-quote)

```
preg_match_all("/ ".preg_quote($argv[1])."/iU", curl("http://tratata.ru/index.html"), $matches);
```

Comment: "Так сделайте дамп $argv и результат curl() и сравните кодировки" - не подскажите как?? var_dump()??? но там же кодировку невидно..

Comment: Если на глаз не получается определить кодировку, то как у сайта посмотреть кодировку я написал выше. 
В консоле - зависит от того как вы к ней подключаетесь. Если через виндовый ssh клиент, то нужно настройки клиента смотреть.
Так-же можно определить кодировку при помощи утилиты [enca][1].

  [1]: http://gitorious.org/enca

Comment: функция  curl()у меня возвращается в UTF-8 а вот $argv я так и не понял НО!!! iconv("", "UTF-8", $argv[1]); вот после такого перекодирования у меня все получилось))

Answer (score 0):

Если на русском, то да, проблема с кодировкой, к сожалению с командной строкой ещё не работал. Обязательно ли через командную строку пользоваться скриптом?

Comment: да (((